# Why data.table row filtering can silently accept a missing argument in a function without raising an error?

Tags: r, data.table

In a function that takes as input a datatable object DT and a range, the function runs without raising an error if the range is used only to filter the rows of the DT.

I have a function in my test suite that was failing because it return a dataframe size different than the expectation. The root cause was that I left out the range argument.

As it was code that I wrote few years ago, I was unsure which of the test expectation and the code is correct. (both on paper are doing what they should do).
The only thing that got me on this track is the missing argument with no error.

Minimal example:

```
library(data.table)

data <- data.table(iris)
select_range <- function(DT, range) {
    DT[range, ]
}

select_range(data)
```

The last call returns the full data while I expected an error for missing argument.

How is this behavior possible as `range` is used by the `DT[range, ]` expression?
What are the recommendations to avoid such surprising effects?

Comment: Try to set `range=NA` in your function definition to get an empty data.table as result.

Comment: FWIW, this isn't unique to `data.table`. `select_range(iris)` also doesn't throw an error. `iris[,]` and `data[,]` both return full tables, as `[` is defined so that if `i` or `j` is missing, the full range is assumed. I agree with Simon, if you want to override the behavior of `[` that allows missing values, you'll need to be explicit. Setting the default value to `NA` will return an empty table. Or adding a check `if(missing(range)) stop("range argument must be specified")` to throw an error.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I feel the proposed style is a bite too defensive for the level of quality I aim for in this code. I'm still surprised that the evaluation of `DT[range, ]` does not force the evaluation of the variable (which would trigger the error?).

Comment: @Gregor please post your comment as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you're having is that `[` doesn't thrown an error when the first (or second) argument is missing. The `data.table` bit is irrelevant--works the same way for data frames, so I'll use data frames as examples for simplicity. `iris[,]` returns the whole data frame, and when your `range` argument is missing, that's the result you get as well.

A fix, in your case, would be to check for the parameter explicitly:

```
select_range <- function(DT, range) {
    if(missing(range)) stop("range must be specified")
    DT[range, ]
}
```

As suggested in comments, you could also use a default value such as `NA` or `0` to return an empty data frame if the range isn't specified.

One might ask why, when `range` is not defined, `DT[range, ]` works inside your function, when in interactive use `iris[range, ]` throws an error (`Error in xj[i] : invalid subscript type 'builtin'`, because it is trying to use the built-in `range()` function), or if we just use an undefined name `iris[askdfj, ]` gives `Error in`[.data.frame`(iris, askdfj, ) : object 'askdfj' not found`. I haven't looked into the C code for `[`, but presumably it must do a check for missingness of the argument, much like in my suggestion above. But instead of throwing an error if the argument is missing, it defaults to all the rows. `missing()` (which, like `[`, is a `.Primitive` C function, tells whether an argument was specified, but it does not check whether the specification is defined. If you run my version of `select_range` passing in an undefined object to the `range` arg, e.g., `select_range(iris, kkjfdfk)`, the `missing` line evaluates to `FALSE`, so that will not cause an error. The error comes from the next line instead.